# Debugging stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to step into the stored procedure code in SQL Server Management Studio? I know this is possible with Visual Studio, but I am looking for a dependable debugging solution from within Management Studio

Comment: Not that I'm aware of in SSMS 2005 - you're left to using PRINT statements & conditional logic/flow control

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  None of the answers below are valid.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Only with SQL 2008 and SSMS 2008. Select from menu 'Debug\Start Debugging' or press Alt+F5 and will launch the step by step T-SQL debugger.

On 2005 the only way is to attach Profiler and monitor for the [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx) event, which is not exactly debugger step-by-step, but at least you'll see the execution flow. Not to be done on a production machine, obviously.

Comment: I get the error "Failed to start debugger" The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug' .. on SSMS 2008

Comment: >> To debug on SQL Server 2005, both the account running Visual Studio and the account used to connect to SQL Server must be members of the sysadmin role. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241735(VS.80).aspx

Comment: And it never occurred to them that people who aren't sys admins might need to debug sps?

Comment: @HLGEM: debugging is somethign you do on the dev box, not on production. Besides, there are very stong reasons for this: anyone with debug priviledges is a de facto admin of the box, simply by means of the power invested in what debuggers can do. So requiring you to be sysadmin is simply aknwoledging a fact and closing a possible priviledge escalation path.

Comment: @RemusRusanu In some companies, software developers write stored procs even though they're not the dba who is the only one with sysadmin priviledges.  Doesn't it make sense to be able to debug your own sp if you're in that role?

Comment: @levininja: no. Development (and step-by-step debug) occurs against your own Developer instance, not against a DBA administered one. The `sysadmin` is in place *exactly* so you do not debug in production (read: hold locks while clicking Step)

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008 and when I select `Debug > Start Debugging` it seems to run all my SQL code at once and does not hit my breakpoints. (I have copied and pasted my sql into a new query).  What am I doing wrong, can you help?

Comment: Turns out I had some errors in the sql that I didn't notice. I had copied this from a stored procedure and it included some `return -1` statements. After I commented these out I was able to debug ok :)

Comment: Down vote. I am using SQL Server 2008 and there isn't a debug menu.

Answer (score 22):

I have written a pretty detailed blog post about it here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/23/debugging-sql-queries-function-amp-stored-procedures-with-sql-management-studio

Basically the gist of it is that you enter your sql query to execute your stored procedure, and instead of pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or hitting the exclamation, you hit the play button and use <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> to step through and step into your stored procs.

This is very handy but no one seems to use it.

Comment: Down vote.  Incorrect.  Pressing the execute button will not start a debugging session, it will only execute the sql.

Answer (score 7):

From SSMS 17 onwards version, You can not debug any SQL.

[Edit]
Use Visual Studio with SSDT tool. You can allow to debug.
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.  M$ has removed all ability to debug SQL with SSMS.

Comment: Check this out, I haven't checked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/191819/how-to-debug-sp-procedure-from-ssms.html

Comment: how do you debug SQL Stored Proc now?

Answer (score 3):

The ability to debug sprocs, which was in Query Analyzer in SQL Server 2000 was not put into SQL Server 2005.  Microsoft realized this mistake and put the functionality back in in SQL Server 2008.

In SSMS 2008 you can start the debugger by either clicking the debug button on the toolbar or pressing ALT+F5.

Unfortunately, running SSMS 2008 against a 2005 database will not allow you to debug, so 
you'll have to stick with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for debugging stored procedures using Visual Studio. The way that this is implemented is to use an incredible amount of locking so that you should never do this on a production system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in SSMS 2008 you can definitely step into T-SQL code (code block, stored func, stored proc) and debug it.

See this excellent article [Management Studio Improvements in SQL Server 2008](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/management-studio-improvements-in-sql-server-2008/) for details - it also deals with debugging (towards the end of the article).

Comment: I get the error "Failed to start debugger" The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug' ..

Comment: Nick you have to be a member of the sysadmin role.