# Debug Insert and temporal tables in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I'm debugging a store procedure that do some `INSERT INTO #temporal table SELECT`.

There is any way to view the data selected in the command (the subquery of the insert into?)
There is any way to view the data inserted and/or the temporal table where the insert maked the changes?

It doesn't matter if is the total rows, not one by one

**UPDATE**:

Requirements from AT Compliance and Company Policy requires that any modification can be done in the process of test and it's probable this will be managed by another team. There is any way to avoid any change on the script?

The main idea is that the AT user check in their workdesktop the outputs, copy and paste them, without make any change on environment or product.

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then take a look at the [**`OUTPUT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application for use in such things as
>   confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
>   requirements.

---

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO #temporaltable 
OUTPUT inserted.*
SELECT *
FROM ...
```

Will give you all the rows from the `INSERT` statement that was inserted into the `temporal` table, which were selected from the other table.

Comment: There is any way to avoid the modification of the SQL in order to make an AT compliance?

Comment: anyway +1 for the help it brings me some new ways out of the box

Comment: If you're going to request that scripts conform to 'AT compliance', perhaps you would indulge us on what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't just do this: `SELECT * FROM #temporal`? (And debug it in SQL Server Management Studio, passing in the same parameters your application is passing in).

It's a quick and dirty way of doing it, but one reason you might want to do it this way over the other (cleaner/better) answer, is that you get a bit more control here. And, if you're in a situation where you have multiple inserts to your temp table (hopefully you aren't), you can just do a single select to see all of the inserted rows at once.

I would still probably do it the other way though (now I know about it).

Comment: If you want to do it without making any changes to the stored proc, you might be out of luck. It is possible to debug scripts (by setting breakpoints and stepping through the script) in Management Studio, but I've never done it and I'm not sure how good it is. This should get you started though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016879/debugging-stored-procedures-in-management-studio

Comment: I use it with @vars in store procedures, but never with queries. It's work fine for me, I like it (and I'm not a MS fan guy at all). Thanks for the link! +1

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do this without changing the script. Howeer, for the future, you should never write a complex strored proc or script without a debug parameter that allows you to put in the data tests you will want. Make it the last parameter with a default value of 0 and you won't even have to change your current code that calls the proc.

Then you can add statements like the below everywhere you will want to check intermediate results. Further in debug mode you might always rollback any transactions so that a bug will not affect the data.

```
IF @debug = 1
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM #temp
END
```

Comment: oh, ok! thanks for the tip. So I'm wonder what is the utility for sql debug if you can't do this kind of debug :S

Comment: Beats me, I never use it as I found it useless for what I need.