# How to debug a tsql procedure?

Tags: asp.net

I just debugged my aspx.vb page and got the values.

I just want to know whether the procedure called in the event can be debugged?

Can I directly debug my procedure through my aspx.vb page?

Comment: execute the procedure and see the output

Comment: Suppose my procedure has more than 20 parameters and I want to see wheather the input value are passing correctly to my procedure or not without executing. then what I need to do.?

Comment: then print the parameters in procedure and see the whether its correct or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016879/debugging-stored-procedures-in-management-studio This might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

In VS.NET go to View - Sql Server Object Explorer. Add a breakpoint in your code and use Execute with Debugger to execute the query with debugging on.

Read more: [How to: Debug Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx)